# ReplaceAll replaces only first occurance of substring

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I would like to replace `"` inside first brackets with `'`. Substring inside second brackets should remain unchanged. Example:

```
String test = "(\"test1\", \"test2\") (\"test3\", \"test4\")"; //wanted output is ('test1', 'test2') ("test3", "test4")
String regex = "(^[^\\)]*?)\"(.*?)\"";
test = test.replaceAll(regex, "$1'$2'");
System.out.println(test); // output is ('test1', "test2") ("test3", "test4")
test = test.replaceAll(regex, "$1'$2'");
System.out.println(test); // output is ('test1', 'test2') ("test3", "test4")
```

Why `"` around test2 are not replaced during first call of replaceAll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the good use-case to use boundary matcher `\G`:

```
String test = "(\"test1\", \"test2\") (\"test3\", \"test4\")";
final String regex = "(^\\(|\\G(?!^),\\h*)\"([^\"]+)\"";

test = test.replaceAll(regex, "$1'$2'");
System.out.println(test);
//=> ('test1', 'test2') ("test3", "test4")
```

`\G` asserts position **at the end of the previous match** or the start of the string for the first match

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8r77OF/2)

Comment: *"or the start of the string"* - that is why you need to use `\\G(?!^)`.